# Handmade carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm making the most simple vertical carousel with a prev/next button. i'm almost there but i haven't figured out the following:

```
var shortnewsblockHeight = $(".shortnewsblock").outerHeight();
var totalnewsblocks = $(".shortnewsblock").length;
var i = 0;
$(".stamp.long a.prev").css({ "opacity": "0.3", "text-decoration": "none", "cursor": "default" });

goDown();
goUp();

function goDown() {
    $(".stamp.long a.next").click(function () {
        $(".stamp.long a.prev").animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        }, 300);
        $(".stamp.long a.prev").css({ "text-decoration": "underline", "cursor": "pointer" });
        i++;
        if (i != (totalnewsblocks - 5)) {
            $("#shortnewsblocks > #inner").stop().animate({
                'marginTop': '-=' + shortnewsblockHeight
            }, 600);
        } else {
            $("#shortnewsblocks > #inner").stop().animate({
                'marginTop': '-=' + shortnewsblockHeight
            }, 600);
            $(".stamp.long a.next").animate({
                'opacity': '0.3'
            }, 300);
            $(".stamp.long a.next").css({ "text-decoration": "none", "cursor": "default" });
            $(".stamp.long a.prev").animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 300);
            $(".stamp.long a.prev").css({ "text-decoration": "underline", "cursor": "pointer" });

        }
        return false;
    });
}

function goUp() {
    $(".stamp.long a.prev").click(function () {
        i--;
        if (i != 0) {
            $("#shortnewsblocks > #inner").stop().animate({
                'marginTop': '+=' + shortnewsblockHeight
            }, 600);
            $(".stamp.long a.next").animate({
                'opacity': '1'
            }, 300);
            $(".stamp.long a.next").css({ "text-decoration": "underline", "cursor": "pointer" });

        } else {
            $("#shortnewsblocks > #inner").stop().animate({
                'marginTop': '+=' + shortnewsblockHeight
            }, 600);
            $(".stamp.long a.prev").animate({
                'opacity': '0.3'
            }, 300);
            $(".stamp.long a.prev").css({ "text-decoration": "none", "cursor": "default" });


        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

1. If i click too fast on the prev/next buttons, the height gets scrambled and my carousel loses its 'block-style' animation.
2. If the carousel runs out of elements to scroll, my buttons fade out (and the cursor becomes default so the end-user won't try to click on it). But i need to make them completely disabled, because now the end-user can still click it, screwing up the carousel.

Cheers!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REVDc/1/

Comment: put your source at http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's not working? I get a JS error in jsfiddle

Comment: k, send the link anyway so ppl could help you. don't forget to add your html and css too.

Comment: It's working, fiddle in main post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `stop` from animations or remove click event when animation is going on.
2. Use `pointer-events: none` to disable clicking. More info available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events).

Comment: 1. Perfect! Thanks!

2. Pointer-events: doesn't work in IE. Although i love the CSS idea, i'd rather go for a JS approach.

Comment: Sure, unbind the click event then.

Comment: Yes, unbinding.. That's what i've been trying to do, but i'm not seeing how i can rebind the stuff (or how to pour it into the current function)